# Problema conceptual en base de datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Buenas noches. Me encuentro creando una base de datos para un juego, por así decirlo, pero observando el modelo Entidad-Relación creado para dicha base de datos, observo que tengo algunos problemas.

Tenemos las entidades Jugadores, Paises,Casillas y Ejércitos.

> La entidad **Jugadores** posee los atributos id, nombre y total_oro.
>
> La entidad **Casillas** posee los atributos id, nombre,
>   tipo('mar','provincia','provincia') y oro_generado.
>
> La entidad **Paises** posee los atributos id, nombre.
>
> La entidad **Ejércitos** posee lo atributos id, nombre.

Ante esto, planteé el siguiente modelo. Los jugadores, poseen Países,al menos 1, por lo que la cardinalidad sería 1:N hacia Paises, ya que un país solo pertenece a un jugador, y Casillas,el jugador puede tener varias casillas y estas solo pertenecen a un jugador o a ninguno, ya que pueden ser mar, por lo que la cardinalidad sería 1:N hacia Casillas.

Los países por su parte, poseen Casillas y estas pueden pertenecer una vez más a un País o a ninguno, otra 1:N, de Países a Casillas. Entonces las entidades pasarían a estar así.

> **Casillas**: id, nombre, tipo('mar','provincia','provincia'),
>   oro_generado, id_jugador e id_país.
>
> **Países**: id, nombre, id_jugador.

Pero observo que esto es un mal diseño, ya que en vez de tres relaciones binarias entre tres entidades, debería hacer una relación ternaria que al pasar al modelo relacional, obtenga la tabla **Jugadores-Casillas-Países** o **Propiedad**(que es más leible), donde obtenga las claves primarias de cada tabla, como clave primaria de esa tabla. 
De esta forma, puedo ver a que jugador corresponde una casilla y a que país corresponde esa casilla.

El primer problema viene cuando necesito poner como nulo un país y jugador en esa tabla, para las casillas que son mar, donde la base de datos me lo impediría, puesto que son claves primarias.

El otro problema surge con la tabla **Ejércitos**, relacionada tambien con **Jugadores** mediante 1:N(un ejercito pertenece a un jugador y un jugador puede tener N), ya que debo relacionarlo con la tabla **Jugadores-Casillas-Países** o **Propiedad** para saber si la posición que ocupo es de una casilla de otro jugador(donde habrá un combate). En este caso, no sé si es posible hacer otra relación ternaria entre **Ejércitos**, **Jugadores** y **Propiedad**, surgida de otra relación ternaria, valga la redundancia.

Comment: Por favor podrías compartir un diagrama o una tentativa de la estructura de la BD para que sea más fácil identificar tus necesidades, así también. Podrías explicar un poco el funcionamiento del juego para poder brindarte una mejor ayuda.

Comment: Ya lo he resuelto, gracias igualmente por el interés.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la tabla **Casillas** la clave primaria es id, y los campos jugador_id y pais_id no son campos clave, así que no hay problema de que sean nulos. En cuanto a la tabla **Ejercitos** ocurre algo similar, si tiene el campo jugador_id podemos saber a qué jugador pertenece ese ejército. Para saber en qué casilla está un ejército podemos agregar un campo casilla_id en la tabla **Ejercitos** porque pueden estar en una sola casilla.

Comment: Al final lo hice así, hacer una relación ternaria me parece que era intentar darle una complejidad que la base de datos no tenía. Gracias por la aportación